# log4net - where do I find XML DTDs or Schema references for things like log4net.Appender.FileAppender configuration?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Where do I find XML DTDs or Schema references for things like log4net.Appender.FileAppender configuration?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174430/log4net-could-not-find-schema-information-messages) someone provides a link (second answer) to a xsd schema definition that you can find [here](http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd). Log4net does not provide a schema definition as far as I know.

Comment: thanks - out of curiosity how would someone normally get at this info via the log4net website if Stackoverflow did not exist?

Comment: I am not quite sure you would find this on the log4net web site :-)

Comment: Is `log4net.xsd` up-to-date?

Comment: I cannot tell for sure, but I do not expect too many changes in log4net (for quite a while the project seemed to be dead).