# Where can I find an XSD for the log4net 1.2.11 release?

Tags: xsd, log4net

I cant find it on Apache's site, it doesn't seem included with the bin or src release... does it not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, they don't provide an XSD.

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549464/log4net-where-do-i-find-xml-dtds-or-schema-references-for-things-like-log4net) with an older XSD from 2008.

Comment: Well it seems to exist for v1.2.10: http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd, I was hoping it would exist for 1.2.11 as there were some things (connection string refs) that I would have preferred validation on.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to download that existing schema, modify it, then use a relative address in your configuration file to reference the schema as I did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11780781/64348.