# Vs2010 using log4net with Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, log4net, intellisense, log4net-configuration

I'm using vs2010 and I need to log a multithreading application.
So I decided to use log4net, but as I'm not used to work with this, Intellisense is gonna be worth.

I download the .xsd from http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd and put this in VSFolder/Xml/Schemas.
But, how can I say to my log4net.config to use the XSD Schema?

Comment: I answered a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11780781/64348), and noted that I updated the author's original schema to allow for custom appenders.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the menu *XML -> Schemas...*

The menu is only there if you have the config file (or any other xml file) open.

Comment: But one point, why VS just recognized my log4net.xsd.XML file and not my file as log4net.XSD ??

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of putting it into a VS folder, **put it somewhere inside your solution's folder tree**. It doesn't even need to be included in any projects. just put it there and it works...

Comment: Note that you will have to close and reopen the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or into: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas and you're sorted once and forever.