# Could not find schema information for attributes in two projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, log4net, app-config

I've created a solution which contains a few projects. One of the projects is my Service project, and the other is the WPF project (for the user interface).

I've been having errors all of the sudden, preventing my application from running. After trying a few things, including reverting to an older working copy in SVN which didn't solve the problem but cost me some improvements, I found out I had messages I probably overlooked before reverting my whole project.

- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ref'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'ref'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'sku'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'type'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.
- Could not find schema information for the attribute 'value'.
- ...

This list goes on for a while and probably every little thing in my `App.config` from my Service-application and three things in my `app.config` from my WPF application is not found.

My `app.config` from my WPF application looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I've seen a few solutions on this site but none of them really worked.
I tried changing the schema to `DotNetConfig30.xsd` instead of `DotNetConfig.xsd` but with no effect. Instead, everything was already listed (instead of not found).

I've also set the projects' build platform to X86, which has no effect neither.

I'm quite stuck here and I have no idea on how to continue. What could be the problem here?

EDIT: After checking all the pointers, it seems `log4net` isn't loaded properly. Every message is from between the `<log4net>` brackets. That happened in the other `App.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="DebugFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="KeyLessAccessService.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="7" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="[%date] %-5level - %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="[%date] %-5level - %logger - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
            <appender-ref ref="DebugFile" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
    <appSettings>
 ....
```

Comment: Which log4net brackets? Have you tried re-adding log4net with nuget?

Comment: I've edited my question and I'll try nuget in a second. Never used that before

Comment: I have readded the package using Nuget, but the problem persisted...

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174430/log4net-could-not-find-schema-information-messages

Comment: I'll try again tomorrow. I've seen the post before but I didn't want to mess with all my configuration files. It did work before so I thought it should be working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure what happened. A restart didn't fix the problem, but leaving the computer out for a night fixed it...