# Could not find schema information in web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am creating an app using mvc web api and I'm using log4net(for the first)

In my web.config I add these lines

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>
    <log4net debug="false">
        <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
            <param name="File" value="C:\Users\Ibrahim\Desktop\Ibrahim\logs\logs.log"/>
            <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n"/>
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="All"/>
            <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
    //other configurations
</configuration>
```

but my web.config is showing me 21 messages stating

> Could not find schema information for the element 'log4net'. {my projectname} {my path} using log4netunitydapp{my projectname}\Web.config 75

after searching around the net i find
[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303476/how-to-fix-error-could-not-find-schema-information-for-the-attribute-element) question related,

i tried some answers like

> Go to the "XML" menu and select "Create Schema". This action should create a new file called "app.xsd" or "web.xsd".

The error was not appearing after this but the log file was not able to save either,

Then I switched to solution number 2

> Right-click on the project icon in Solution Explorer and choose "Properties".
> Go to the "Application" tab and choose an earlier .NET target framework.
> Save changes.
> Go to the "Application" tab and choose the initial .NET target framework.
> Save changes => problem solved!

I even Changed My .Net framework to 2 but the problem is still not solved

Then I switched to this solution

> When this happened to me (out of nowhere) I was about to dive into the top answer above, and then I figured I'd close the project, close Visual Studio, and then re-open everything. Problem solved. VS bug?

and this didn't help either, what should be the possible solution for this?

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174430/log4net-could-not-find-schema-information-messages

Comment: great!! Have a nice day ahead!!!!

Comment: @PowerStar thanks mate